# How to Add fade transition effect for slide elements

Tags: jquery, slideshow

How to Add fade transition effect for slide elements

I have implemented the slider but i am not able to add slide transition effect to my slider.Below is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#slide_show').ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 4000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apps4any/uugbz6va/

Reference link with slide transition
http://www.jssor.com/demos/simple-fade-slideshow.html